# Wso2 Identity Server Oauth Token expiry time is calculated wrongly in OAuth2TokenValidation.validate SOAP service

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have successfully configured a service provider in Wso2 Identity server. With Oauth2 as inbound authentication method. I am facing some issue in Access Token Expiry time. I debugged the issue by following steps

1. Using Generate Token API - https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token - i got generated access token as response. 
   data`{"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"a0e09620d3185a6f7dc2cd42f092e76c","access_token":"b2267f60892c6c94f58a421d2d529a"}`
2. In above response the expiry time is **3600**. which is same as configured in identity.xml. But When I use this access_token in OAuth2TokenValidation.validate SOAP service, the expiry time is completely  doubled as 360000.
3. I have test this in soap UI tool. I have attached a screen shot of it. [image]

Is there anything, i am missing from configuration side or some issue at calculation of expiry time at OAuth2TokenValidation validation soap api. Need help to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value on *`$IS_HOME/reposotory/conf/identity.xml`* file.

The tag is ***`<AuthorizationContextTTL>15</AuthorizationContextTTL>`***. And, the default value is *15*.